# Two usb-ethernet device of same brand connected same time

Tags: windows-10, usb, ethernet

I have two usb-to-ethernet device from same brand: Realtek; let say dev1 and dev2

When I insert dev1, windows recognizes it as `Realtek USB GbE Family Controller`.

Then I insert dev2 and windows recognizes it as `Realtek USB GbE Family Controller #2`.

I set an IPv4 for dev1 as 192.168.0.x, and for dev2 as 192.168.1.x.

All works fine!

The problem occurs when I restart PC while these 2 devices are already connected.

I guess that windows get confused of having 2 Realtek USB GbE Family Controller, cannot deciding which one is #2, as when inserting them one by one.

Then I have to remove all (including usb hub where dev1 and dev2 are connected), then again inserting one by one, and in the same order to keep IPv4 settings equal.

The question is:

How could I achieve the setup that I have defined after restarting, without having to repeat inserting the devices with a specific order?

Comment: USB is less than ideal for this. Indeed these two devices may work as if they were indistinguishable.

Comment: Instead of trying to force the OS to enumerate the adapters your way, instead use the default assignments that occur on startup.  IOW redefine your setup to match the OS.

Comment: @sawdust Those are what OS assigns automatically, but only when inserting them one by one, after each restart. If they are already connected when restarting, then OS does not recognize any of both.

Comment: Then you have done a poor job describing Windows behavior.  Instead you only tell what you guess: *"I guess that windows get confused ..."*.  You need to update your post with a real description and more details.

Comment: The device's IP addresses are the important information, and in a properly configured network it is unlikely the device or OS will be assigning this information. Can you take some time to more clearly state what the desired outcome is, and how it isn't working?

Comment: @music2myear IPs are not the problem, I have commented about IPs just to inform why I have 2 usb-ethernet device. "The problem occurs when I restart PC while these 2 devices are already connected.": PC is closed. You have connected 2 usb-ethernet device to PC. Restarts PC. Then nothing sees in Device Manager. You have to remove them, and insert to PC one by one.